# Automatically update a data source (Excel doc, from ServiceNow) in PowerApps

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, servicenow

The question here is: *Am I on the right path (this is the first time I'm trying this), and if not, what would be smarter to try? If this is the right path, can you offer suggestions on how to do this best, because if this works, I am going to use it often on a lot of different tasks in this app.*

I'm running a PowerApps Canvas app. As part of its program, I want it to be able to reference (read-only) a collection of data. That data is in ServiceNow, and my group is not permitted to access ServiceNow using the API.

During *testing* of the app, I just had it reference a SharePoint list (which I had filled with some dummy data), but I can re-code those lines as needed to pull from some other data source.

Because I am touching a few different systems here, I am not sure if this is the right way to go and I'm afraid I'll spend too long trying and find out that it would never have worked because of x. Thus my question.

This is what I think will work. Am I headed in the right direction?

1. Set up the scheduled report in ServiceNow. (Done!)
2. Program ServiceNow to email the Excel file output. Make sure it is
   always the same title. (Done!)
3. Build a Power Automate flow to capture that email and save the
   attached file to a location (OneDrive?) that can be accessed by the
   app. If there is a file there already, delete it first.
4. Add the Excel file as a data source to the app, and start
   referencing it as needed.
5. 8-12 hours later, ServiceNow pushes out another scheduled data
   drop, and the whole thing updates again.

In my perfect world, this system would work completely unattended.

Offhand, a glitch I can see is that ServiceNow generates an Excel file, but it's not a table, and PowerApps I think must ingest as a data source an Excel file that is a table. But (shrug) I might be wrong.

Am I thinking of this correctly? Is this the best avenue to follow?